# Is $\rho(x,y)=(x-y)^2$, with $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^1$, a metric space on $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Obviously it has to satisfy the following:

1) For all $x,y\in X$, $0\le d(x,y)$. (positivity)

2) For all $x,y\in X$, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. (symmetry)

3) For all $x,y,z\in X$, $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. (triangle-inequality)

This is a homework problem and I'm not sure where to even start. I'm new to the concept of metric spaces and would appreciate any help/direction.

If x=y, then $\rho(x,y)=\rho(x,x)=(x-x)^2=0$. I'm assuming that will suffice for (1).

Comment: what is denoted by $X$?

Comment: Does 3) hold for $\rho$? Try testing with particular values of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you don't know where to start... You may be new to the "concept" of a metric space, but the definition of distance is what you've written, so... just try the three conditions and see if they hold

Comment: After testing 3) with specific values, I believe it holds.

Answer (score 4):

$d(x,y)=(x-y)^2$

checking for 3rd axiom:

$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2 =x^2 -2xy + y^2 +y^2 -2yz +z^2\\=x^2 -2xz +z^2 +2xz -2xy + y^2 +y^2 -2yz\\=(x-z)^2+2x(z-y)-2y(z-y)\\=(x-z)^2+2(z-y)(x-y)  $$
It means 
$$(x-z)^2=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2-2(z-y)(x-y)$$
Now to satisfy the third axiom $2(z-y)(x-y)\ge0$ which is not possible say for 
$x<y<z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at 1) as an example. You want to prove/disprove that
$$\rho(x,y) = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$$
for any pair of real numbers $x$and $y$. Since the square of something is always non-negative, we can see that this holds.

But for $\rho$ to be a metric, 2) and 3) must hold as well! Try proving 2) by noting that
$$(x-y)^2 = (-y + x)^2 = ((-1)(y - x))^2 = (-1)^2(y-x)^2 = (y-x)^2$$

For 3), try plugging in the specific values that David Mitra mentioned in the comments of your question. Do you see that this is a counter-example? What is your final conclusion about $\rho$?

EDIT: There is a fourth axiom which you forgot to mention: That $d(x,y) = 0$ happens if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Thank you for bringing to my attention the fourth axiom. After using specific values for 2) and 3), my conclusion is that they both hold and thus, $\rho$ is a metric.

Comment: Although I'm confused about the counter-example. Are you able to explain it to me?

Comment: So you checked that 2) and 3) were true for some specific values, and concluded that they were true for all values?

Comment: That is true, I would have to prove it holds for all values.

Comment: Yes. Using the definition of your metric and the fact that $(x-y)^2 = (y-x)^2$, the proof of 2) just pops out. Can you see this? For 3), try plugging in $x = 0$, $y = 1$ and $z = 1/2$. Does the equation in 3) hold for these values?

Comment: Oh yes, the proof of 2) is clear. Also, when I test x=0, y=1, and z=1/2, 3) holds. I'm assuming that it is a counter-example and I'm doing something wrong. This is my work...

Comment: $d(0,1) = 1$, $d(0,1/2) = 1/4$, $d(1/2,1) = 1/4$. Surely $1 \leq 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2$ doesn't hold?

Comment: d(0, 1)<=d(0, 1/2)+d(1/2, 1) implies |0-1|<=|0-1/2|+|1/2-1| implies 1<=1/2 + 1/2 implies 1<=1.

Comment: Oh I see, I need to use (x-y)^2 instead of absolute value

Comment: Therefore 3) does not hold and thus, $\rho$ is not a metric.

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I now understand it much better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the triangle-inequality : let $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=2$, then $\rho(x,y)=1$, $\rho(y,z)=1$, and $\rho(x,z)=4$. From "triangle-inequality" we should have
$$\rho(x,z) \leq \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)$$
i.e.
$$4 \leq 1 + 1$$
and that's not true, therefore $\rho$ is not a metric.

Answer (score 0):

$$ρ(x,z)=(x−z)^2=(x−y+y-z)^2=(x−y)^2 +(y−z)2 +2(z−y)(x−y)= ρ(x,y)+ρ(y,z)+2(z−y)(x−y),$$
$$ρ(x,z)= ρ(x,y)+ρ(y,z)+2(z−y)(x−y)$$

So  triangular inequality is not satisfied in general.